# Is there a predefind function to check for null, undefined, or blank variables in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

```
<div 
ng-if='documentData.addressesList[0] == undefined 
||documentData.addressesList[0] == ""
|| documentData.addressesList[0] == null'>
     View
  </div>
```

Or is their any other way to create a user defined function which checks all these three condition in once.

Comment: angular is javascript and what you are asking is javasript related, not angular. Please provide more details regarding specific issues

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function to check wether object is defined or not (is null or undefined):

```
angular.isDefined(value);
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isDefined

According to your edit, you can just use

```
<div ng-if='documentData.addressesList[0]'>View</div>
```

in your view

Comment: i want to apply the check on html not in controller, thnx for answer

Comment: It Works for me. Thnx

Answer (score 0):

In your view you could just use

```
<div ng-if='!documentData.addressesList[0]'>
```

This assumes you wouldn't use `"0"` as a value

In javascript terms:

```
if(!"")//true
if(!null)//true
if(!undefined)//true
```

So there isn't a need to use all of those conditions that you use

Comment: if i use <div ng-if='!documentData.addressesList[0]'>  than will it check if my variable has a value.(Added "!" before variale)